# Is there a way to dynamically import a Vue component from the Laravel/Inertia backend based on a successful authentication check?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

In an application with user profiles where a user can view information about themselves, I would like to add a 'Delete this user' button that only appears for logged-in admin users.

Using Inertia, I can check a user is an admin on the backend, then serve the page with `return inertia('Page', [admin => true]);` in the page data, and render the button based on that boolean.

My concern is that if there is sensitive information in the component that should only be shown to admins (let's say, in this example, I don't want users to know an admin can delete their account), a user has still downloaded that component when they loaded the page which imports it, even if through normal usage it would not be rendered into their DOM.

How can we get around this issue? Is it possible to entirely hide the existence of a Vue 3 component behind an authentication gate when using Laravel & InertiaJS?

For example, if I wanted to hide all evidence of the button in an application using blade for layout, I might do:

```
@if($admin === true)
<button onClick="http://my-secret-url.com/">Delete user</button>
@endif
```

Which doesn't provide the user with an opportunity to intercept the response from the server and change the 'admin' variable to `true` in order to see the button.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you send "admin" prop as true, you can use the v-if directive to hide the button.

Comment: @cdruc that's true, but the button is still sent to the client in the JS files for the page, and a particularly savvy user could intercept the server response and set the "admin" prop to true to have the page render as it would for an admin. I have edited the question to elaborate a bit with an example of how I would do this using Laravel blade directives. My hope is that I can prevent any information on the button being sent to the client if they aren't authorised by the server to use it.

Comment: even if the user would be able to uncover that button and see/access that url/action, you should have protection on your backend (see Laravel Gates and Policies: ) that prevent them from executing undesired actions.

Imho you're worrying too much. As long as your backend is properly protected, the user can see and try to access whatever they want - the end action won't work.